# Registering two complex meshes

Tags: mesh

I am trying to use Meshroom and Blender to demonstrate a lesion in a case I'm working on.  I have digitized the top and the bottom of a skull using Meshroom, which creates meshes from multiple photographs:

[image]

I have done the top and bottom of the cranium separately, and have cleaned them up a bit, but now I need to register and merge the two parts:

[image]

I know how to join the two meshes once they are registered, I think, but I don't know if there's a way to register the meshes other than just visually, since it requires scaling as well as positioning.  I'm finding that scaling it exactly is the hardest part.  Doing it visually is difficult to get "just right."

[image]

Is there an addon or method for doing this easily?  I know there will always be some vertices sticking out -- these meshes are just a little noisy -- and I think I know how to clean them up.  But the initial registration is a pain.  Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: What does "registering" a mesh mean?

Comment: Sorry.  I'm used to the medical computer vision literature and not the graphics one.  Registration is aligning data so that they are in continuity.  For instance, aligning slices of a CT scan in order to create a 3D model of an organ is "registering" the slices.

Comment: The problem here is that since these meshes come from two data sets, the edges will never align perfectly, and there will be some overlap between the two data sets.  Most algorithms involve minmizing some error measure.  See, for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration

Comment: Is there any point(s) for which you know the correspondance between the meshes?

Comment: Do you have access to the skull ? Maybe you can try to "photogrammetrise" (I don't know the verb) it again but this time, add little dots on some parts that you know are touching when the skull is complete. Then use a Helmert Transform to find the homothety between the two. But AFAIK there is no standard way to do it in Blender.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Yeah, I can sit down and puzzle out some fiducial points on both meshes.  I don't have to redo the digitization -- the quality of the mesh is sufficient for me to find some correspondences.